# How to update a column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In `Pandas`, I am trying to add a new column / update an existing column to a data frame (DF2) with a value from another data frame (DF1).  I can think of how to do this in `SQL`

```
UPDATE DF2
SET DF2['Column'] = DF1['Column']
FROM DF2
JOIN DF1 ON DF1['NonIndexColumn'] = DF2['NonIndexColumn']
```

Data Example:

```
d =[{'CustomerID': 1, 'SignUpDate': '2014-01-01'}, {'CustomerID': 2, 'SignUpDate': '2014-02-01'}, {'CustomerID': 3, 'SignUpDate': '2014-03-01'}, {'CustomerID': 4, 'SignUpDate': '2014-04-01'}]
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = [{'OrderID': 1, 'CustomerID': 1, 'OrderDate': '2014-01-15'}, {'OrderID': 2, 'CustomerID': 1, 'OrderDate': '2014-01-15'}, {'OrderID': 3, 'CustomerID': 2, 'OrderDate': '2014-03-28'}, {'OrderID': 4, 'CustomerID': 1, 'OrderDate': '2014-03-29'}, {'OrderID': 5, 'CustomerID': 3, 'OrderDate': '2014-04-28'}, {'OrderID': 6, 'CustomerID': 2, 'OrderDate': '2014-06-01'}, {'OrderID': 7, 'CustomerID': 1, 'OrderDate': '2014-11-06'}, {'OrderID': 8, 'CustomerID': 3, 'OrderDate': '2015-01-28'}, {'OrderID': 9, 'CustomerID': 1, 'OrderDate': '2015-02-15'} ]
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

I am trying to add `DF1['SignUpDate']` on to `DF2`, so that `DF2` would look like this:

```
       CustomerID   OrderDate  OrderID  SignUpDate
0           1  2014-01-15        1      2014-01-01
1           1  2014-01-15        2      2014-01-01
2           2  2014-03-28        3      2014-02-01
3           1  2014-03-29        4      2014-01-01
4           3  2014-04-28        5      2014-03-01
5           2  2014-06-01        6      2014-02-01
6           1  2014-11-06        7      2014-01-01
7           3  2015-01-28        8      2014-03-01
8           1  2015-02-15        9      2014-01-01
```

I know the `merge` would allow me to add the column, but I would have to either overwrite the existing DF or create a new one, like this:

```
DF1 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2) #overwrite
DF3 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2) #new dataframe
```

Is there not a way to join on one field (maybe an indexed column, maybe not an indexed column) and update / add the field?

Comment: Please post raw data and desired output, it really depends on how your data's relationship is with each other but you could try `df1['Column'] = df2['Column'].where((df1['NonIndexedColumn'] == df2['NonIndexedColumn'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a left [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [4]:

DF2.merge(DF1, on='CustomerID', how='left')
Out[4]:
   CustomerID   OrderDate  OrderID  SignUpDate
0           1  2014-01-15        1  2014-01-01
1           1  2014-01-15        2  2014-01-01
2           2  2014-03-28        3  2014-02-01
3           1  2014-03-29        4  2014-01-01
4           3  2014-04-28        5  2014-03-01
5           2  2014-06-01        6  2014-02-01
6           1  2014-11-06        7  2014-01-01
7           3  2015-01-28        8  2014-03-01
8           1  2015-02-15        9  2014-01-01
```

Comment: I got that to work.  Thanks.  In SQL, you can alter a table and add a new column.  In `pandas`, specifically with this merge, I would need to overwrite DF2.  Is that standard `pandas` functionality just to overwrite?

Comment: No you can conditionally overwrite but it depends on the relationship between the 2 dfs, so you could either mask or select the rows of interest from the lhs and rhs and assign the values